# web2py error while using distinct in the queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I am using web2py with GAE. While using some of the queries which has a distinct clause, GAE throws out an error.I have pasted the Traceback. Can someone  please help me out with this.

```
In FILE: /base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/applications/init/controllers/default.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/gluon/restricted.py", line 173, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/applications/init/controllers/default.py:profileview", line 263, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/gluon/globals.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/applications/init/controllers/default.py:profileview", line 97, in profileview
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/gluon/contrib/gql.py", line 675, in select
    (items, tablename, fields) = self._select(*fields, **attributes)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/panneersoda/1.341206242889687944/gluon/contrib/gql.py", line 624, in _select
raise SyntaxError, 'invalid select attribute: %s' % key
SyntaxError: invalid select attribute: distinct
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry distinct does not work on GAE, only RDBS.